# 2005 Polaris Predator ATV starting problem

Tags: starting, atv, polaris, predator

I have a 2005 Polaris Predator 500. I was riding it one day to the store and turned it off when I came back out to try and start it all it did was make a clicking noise. Once I got it home I tried to start it with the solenoid and screwdriver and the screwdriver started glowing red hot and it was throwing a tremendous amount of spark. I order a replacement solenoid off Amazon and it's still doing the same thing. If anyone could assist me on the next step to solve this problem or what you think it could be will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like you are grounding your positive battery lead instead of energizing your solenoid. There should be three  poles/posts on the solenoid: power in from battery (thick); power out to starter (thick); energizer (thin). To get your solenoid to energize, you need to put your screwdriver from the power in pole to the energizer pole. If you are touching anything else you are creating a short to ground and causing the sparks.

Comment: Was clicking from the starter solenoid or starter? Are you positive of bypassing the ignition switch and shorting the correct starter solenoid terminals to power the starter? Do you know the condition of the starter? Is the engine flooded, creating a hydraulic lock against compression, preventing the engine from turning over while starting?

Comment: When I hit the electric start button the clicking sound comes from the starter. When I use the solenoid it throws soo much spark you would thing I had a grinder on there and the screwdriver almost solders itself to the solenoid .but the solenoid also clicks when I use it also it's just nothing happens after the click sound. No it's not flooded or seized as far as I know.

Comment: Ok I'll try that next and it should be three wires connected to the positive side of the solenoid or the battery?